# MIME parameter values should be sourronded by double quotes

Tags: c#, mime, mimekit

I have an app in c# that receives and sends files in MIME format, but they aren't exactly mails.

I'm using MimeKit and I need that all parameter values be sourronded by double quotes (").

Does exist any configuration in MimeKit to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MimeKit will quote parameter values only if they need to be quoted.

It is open source, though, so if you want it to quote everything, you can modify the code to do that.